# How to set webroot in Java Socket server

Tags: java, websocket, server

For the first time I'm creating a socket based Java server.
I faced a problem where I need to translate request targets to actual paths I expect to be accessed by client.
I would like to set the webroot once and don't need to interpret request targets.

It is a kind of question where it's difficult to provide an appropriate piece of code but here's what server thread looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ServerThread(int port) throws IOException {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Server started");

        try {
            while (serverSocket.isBound() && !serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                ConnectionThread connectionThread = new ConnectionThread(socket);
                connectionThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (serverSocket != null) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path))

Comment: Oh so there's no way of indication where requests starts in relation with server files?

Comment: The request contains a path which is relative to the context

Comment: Ok I think I just got the idea. Thank You very much for responding ^^